# Is there a private using name = type;

Tags: c++, c++11, private, using

I want to write:

```
namespace A{
    using name = type;
}
```

But if I try to use it from another space it would be available. Can I make it private inside its namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no language feature to allow that, but many projects have the convention that all contents of namespaces named `detail` are reserved and should not be used.

```
namespace A {
    namespace detail {
        using name = type;
    }

    //something using detail::name
}

//A::detail::name technically accessible, but disallowed by convention
```

Answer (score 5):

No you can't: namespaces are (loosely speaking) `public`, unless the whole thing is within an *anonymous namespace* in which case it's only visible to that compilation unit.

```
namespace{
    namespace A{
        using name = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this work: `namespace A { namespace {using name=type;} name x;}` ? If I understood correctly, this would make `name` kind of private to `A`, while in your snippet the complete namespace `A` is not visible in another compilation unit.